# req.session.passport.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-local

I can not find the error, my method does not serialize the user. 
Within passport.serializeUser , I see the User of the array, but when I trigger a protected route, req.isAuthenticated , always returns me false

My passport file:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    console.log('OK')//is show in console
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user)
    });
});

passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, username, password, done){

    process.nextTick(function(){
        User.findOne({'username' : username}, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false);
            }
            if(!user.validPassword(password)){
                return done(null, false);
            }
            return done(null, user);

        });
    });
}
))
```

My login route:

```
app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user){
        if(err){
            res.json({sucesso: false, mensagem: 'Erro ao logar', erro: err});
        }
        else{
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    console.log('ERRO ' + err);
                }
                else{
                    var token = jwt.encode(user, 'JwTaUtHaNGULAR');
                    return res.send({sucesso: true, token: 'JWT ' + token, mensagem: 'Autenticação OK'});
                }
            });

        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Here is my protected route:

```
app.get('/api/dashboard/users', isLogged ,function(req, res){
    Usuario.find({'_id': {$ne: id_user}}, function(err, usuario){
        res.json({sucesso: true, user: usuario});
    });
});
```

My function that checks whether the user is authenticated:

```
function isLogged(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    else{
        console.log('ERRO');
    }

}
```

Here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var config = require('./config/database');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err, db){
    if(!err){
        console.log('Conectado');
    }
});

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var cors = require('cors');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: 'SecretSession', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.use(cors());

require('./app/routes')(app, passport);

server.listen(3030, function(){
    console.log('Rodando ');
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You seem to be mixing JWT's with "regular" (cookie-based) sessions, which may be an issue. Also, are you using AJAX to retrieve the protected route? If so, make sure that it uses [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials). If you're using Angular, see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) (look for the `withCredentials` option).

Comment: Yes, I use ajax . I configured withCredentials : true , but the error persists

Comment: And I enabled CORS also

Comment: `express-session` will set cookies itself, but you're also using `cookie-parser` (and both use a different secret?). Perhaps that's causing an issue.

Comment: I change the secrete, same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

You are deserializing users by their ID but serialize them by using the whole user object. Try changing `passport.serializeUser` to

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    console.log('OK')//is show in console
    done(null, user.id);
});
```

so you are also serializing users by their ID. Additionally it looks like you are using two different mongoose models `User` and `Usuario` for users is this intended?

**Update:** I took another look at your code and agree with the above commentator. You are mixing up session-based authentication and token-based authentication. You reply with a JWT in `passport.authenticate` but do not use it later in `isLogged` to verify the authentication (like you would normally do in a token-based approach).

So the solution in my opinion is to remove JWTs. Using session cookies *and* a token does not make much sense in your case (if you disagree please leave a comment *why* you are using JWTs). So apply the above `serializeUser` fix and simply use the default `passport.authenticate('local')` callback and your code should work as expected.

Comment: I Tried to Change user to user.id and user._id but still not serializing. The users of models are the same

Comment: Same problem. I removed the JWT , made ​​another request with the angular , but the problem persists